# How To Get Childs From Json Response Firebase

Tags: json, python-3.x, firebase-realtime-database

```
current_date = date.today()


result = firebase.get('/InstaFollow',None)

data = json.dumps(result,indent=2)
print(data)
```

Python

```
{
  "User2Follow": {
    "16_04_2020": {
      "20:20:51": {
        "Delightedtiktoks": "\"55822\""
      },
      "20:21:04": {
        "Delightedtiktoks": "\"55822\""
      },
      "20:38:45": {
        "Delightedtiktoks": "\"Testuser101\""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hey Guys Im Making A Project With Python,And Im Stuck.
Im Using A realtime database from firerbase,this is my response(Json)
Im Trying To Get A List With The Dates "16_04_2020"(This JSON File only has 1 date,but there will be more )
Anyone Know How I Can Get A List With All Dates?
So if would run my script my output should be :  "16_04_2020"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```py
import json

myjson = '''
{
  "User2Follow": {
    "16_04_2020": {
      "20:20:51": {
        "Delightedtiktoks": "55822"
      },
      "20:21:04": {
        "Delightedtiktoks": "55822"
      },
      "20:38:45": {
        "Delightedtiktoks": "Testuser101"
      }
    }
  }
}'''

object = json.loads(myjson)
dates = [date for date in object['User2Follow']]
print(dates)
```

Output:

```
['16_04_2020']
```

Comment: Thank You So Much By Using Ur Code I Was Able To Implement The Last Part And It Worked :),if u dont mind can u send a docs link for this type of json proccessing i couldnt find any docs on this.

Comment: actually it's not about json processing. `json.loads` returns a dict or an array(dict in this case) and you should work with that. i think you should read more about that.

Comment: thx i didnt realise when the json was turned into a python object i could use that data